# Django User and AbstractBaseUser

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am working on creating a website with user profiles but I have run into a problem.  I am very confused about how `User` works in Django.  Here is my current code:
 In `Models.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    biography = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    votes = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
        auto_now=False, null=True
        )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user.username)

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    body = models.TextField(blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    votes = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.title)
```

In my `settings.py` I have `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'models.Profile'` set.

Now When I go into the `Admin` site and create a new `Profile`, it has a `User` field where I have to choose a user.  The `User` that I have to choose from is my Django Admin superuser that I created with `python manage.py createsuperuser`. To create a new `User` entirely and not be linked to the Django Admin superuser, should I be making a custom `User` using `AbstractBaseUser` instead?  I followed some tutorials and they seem to all use the `auth.User` method. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you better use ForeignKey in Post Model, since one person can have many posts, right?

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="user_profile")
    ...

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name="user_posts")
```

and you dont set `AUTH_USER_MODEL`, you set it if you want to customize the authentication backend, I think you want to use django's built-in User Model to authentication. so no need for `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in settings

with the models above, you can access profile in views like this:

```
user_profile = request.user.user_profile
user_profile.keywords
...
```

and in admin, you just need to create another new django user object, to be able to assign it to a new user profile object.

Comment: Thanks for the info! It seems to be working as I need.  Now the admin page shows the username of each `Profile` object and not the `superuser` name. When I make a new user by making a `Profile` object through my views, they show no `User` selected in their admin page. Instead it is blank, but I am still able to choose a `User` from the dropdown box. That doesn't feel correct to me.

Comment: @tear728 if you create a new user profile, it is clear that the new profile doesnot have a user model relation yet, hence the empty dropdown.

Comment: yeah i just figured that out when I went and tried to add the new profile to a user with a profile already assigned to it and it wouldn't let me. thanks again